# Deserialize JSON into polymorphic POJO with JSON-B / Yasson

Tags: java, resteasy, quarkus, jsonb-api, yasson

I have a PATCH endpoint in a resource class with an abstract class as a request body.
I'm getting the following error:

```
22:59:30 SEVERE [or.ec.ya.in.Unmarshaller] (on Line: 64) (executor-thread-63) Can't create instance
```

It seems that because the body model that i'm declaring as an argument is abstract so it fail to deserialize.

I'm expecting to get either Element_A or Element_B

How can I declare the body to be polymorphic?

This is the elements hierarchy

```
public abstract class BaseElement {
    public String name;
    public Timestamp start;
    public Timestamp end;
}

public class Element_A extends BaseElement{
    public String A_data;
}

public class Element_B extends BaseElement{
    public long B_data;
}
```

this is the resource class with my endpoint

```
@Path("/myEndpoint")
public class ResourceClass {

    @PATCH
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public Response updateEvent(@Valid BaseElement element, @Context UriInfo uriInfo, @PathParam long id) {
        if (element instanceof Element_A) {
            // Element_A logic
        } else if (element instanceof Element_B) {
            // Element_B logic
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("working").type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
    }
}
```

This is the request body that I'm sending in a PATCH request

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "startTime": "2020-02-05T17:50:55",
  "endTime": "2020-02-05T17:51:55",
  "A_data": "it's my data"
}
```

I've also tried to add @JsonbTypeDeserializer with a custom deserializer which didn't work

```
@JsonbTypeDeserializer(CustomDeserialize.class)
public abstract class BaseElement {
    public String type;
    public String name;
    public Timestamp start;
    public Timestamp end;
}
```

```
public class CustomDeserialize implements JsonbDeserializer<BaseElement> {

    @Override
    public BaseElement deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context, Type rtType) {
        JsonObject jsonObj = parser.getObject();
        String type = jsonObj.getString("type");

        switch (type) {
            case "A":
                return context.deserialize(Element_A.class, parser);
            case "B":
                return context.deserialize(Element_B.class, parser);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

This is the new request I sent:

```
{
  "type": "A"
  "name": "test",
  "startTime": "2020-02-05T17:50:55",
  "endTime": "2020-02-05T17:51:55",
  "A_data": "it's my data"
}
```

Throws this error:

```
02:33:10 SEVERE [or.ec.ya.in.Unmarshaller] (executor-thread-67) null
02:33:10 SEVERE [or.ec.ya.in.Unmarshaller] (executor-thread-67) Internal error: null
```

My pom.xml include:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy-jsonb</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

JSON-B doesn't have ideal support for polymorphic deserialization yet, so at best you can do a sort of workaround for now. We have a design issue open for it here: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/jsonb-api/issues/147, so please vote for it by giving it a `+1`!

You have the right idea with a custom deserializer, but the issue is that you cannot parse the current `JsonObject` and then later call `context.deserialize()` with the same parser, because the parser has already advanced past the state where it read the JSON object. (The JSONParser is a forward-only parser so there isn't a way to "rewind" it)

So, you can still call `parser.getObject()` in your custom deserializer, but then you need to use a separate `Jsonb` instance to parse that particular JSON string once you have determined its concrete type.

```java
public static class CustomDeserialize implements JsonbDeserializer<BaseElement> {

  private static final Jsonb jsonb = JsonbBuilder.create();

  @Override
  public BaseElement deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context, Type rtType) {

      JsonObject jsonObj = parser.getObject();
      String jsonString = jsonObj.toString();
      String type = jsonObj.getString("type");

      switch (type) {
        case "A":
          return jsonb.fromJson(jsonString, Element_A.class);
        case "B":
          return jsonb.fromJson(jsonString, Element_B.class);
        default:
          throw new JsonbException("Unknown type: " + type);
      }
  }
}
```

---

Side notes: You need to change the base object model to the following:

```java
  @JsonbTypeDeserializer(CustomDeserialize.class)
  public abstract static class BaseElement {
    public String type;
    public String name;
    @JsonbProperty("startTime")
    public LocalDateTime start;
    @JsonbProperty("endTime")
    public LocalDateTime end;
  }
```

1. Assuming you can't or don't want to change your JSON schema, you can either change your java field names (`start` and `end`) to match the JSON field names (`startTime` and `endTime`) OR you can use the `@JsonbProperty` annotation to remap them (which I have done above)
2. Since your timestamps are in the ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME format, I would suggest using `java.time.LocalDateTime` instead of `java.sql.Timestamp` because `LocalDateTime` handles time zones, but ultimately either way will work given the sample data you provided